# Terminix: No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, gedit, budgie

I am using Ubuntu Budgie and using Terminix as terminal alternative.

I have two users a and b, when I login with user a and use 'gedit .bashrc', gedit works.

However, when I switch to user b using 'su b' and run 'gedit .bashrc', I am getting the following error.

```
****No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:7211): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0****
```

I tried to use the fix this by following methods.

1. Manually set display variable.

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0.0 //Doesn't work.
   ```

I even tried adding the line to `.bashrc` and sourcing it. Doesn't work either.

2. Tried setting xTerm.

   ```
   xhost +local:
   No protocol specified
   xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
   ```

Still same error is shown.

3. Copy .Xauthority of one user to other. This too doesn't work.

Seems I am unable to launch any text editor (Atom,Sublime etc.) from terminix.

Comment: afaik that's normal when trying to `su` and start a graphical program. You will be able to use `vim` or `nano` ;) but there should be a way with `xhost`, I've just not managed to figure it out myself yet

Comment: AFAIK `xhost +local:` should work (when run from the session of the user who owns the display of course - i.e. as user `a` *before* you `su b`)

Comment: Yes vim and nano works, but doesn't work with gedit. I have no idea why..

Comment: Thanks @afaik, I tried your answer and it works!!!. Seems the mistake I did is switching to user 'b' and then trying to hand over control. Instead of executing the command as 'a' and switching to 'b'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try reverting to xorg before logging in. I was having the same issue. Just remember to change back to Wayland. Should this be on a bug report someplace?

Comment: Explicit hand over of control works fine. I am not sure whether this is a bug or not. This occurred to me because of the configuration problem with users on my system.